# Ordering an Array using Another Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to solve this LeetCode question - https://leetcode.com/problems/create-target-array-in-the-given-order/description/ where the instructions contains -

Given two arrays of integers nums and index. Your task is to create target array under the following rules:

Initially target array is empty.
From left to right read nums[i] and index[i], insert at index index[i] the value nums[i] in target array.
Repeat the previous step until there are no elements to read in nums and index.
Return the target array.

It is guaranteed that the insertion operations will be valid.

I tried out this approach but it is not working as expected.

```
public class LeetCode1389 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(createTargetArray(new int[]{0,1,2,3,4}, new int[]{0,1,2,2,1})));
    }

    static int[] createTargetArray(int[] nums, int[] index) {
        int[] target = new int[nums.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < index.length; j++){
                target[index[i]] = nums[i];
            }
        }
        return target;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Please give more details than "not working as expected"? Any specific test cases you fail? 2. Why the inner loop? You don't use `j` anywhere and it seems it's just a pointless inner loop.

Comment: This is one of the cases i am using - 
Input: nums = [0,1,2,3,4], index = [0,1,2,2,1]
Output: [0,4,1,3,2]
Explanation:
nums       index     target
0            0        [0]
1            1        [0,1]
2            2        [0,1,2]
3            2        [0,1,3,2]
4            1        [0,4,1,3,2]

Comment: I think by "insert" they actually mean "put in that position and shift right every other value". The simplest (though probably not fastest) way to implement that in Java is to use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Yes that is correct. How do i push the values in an array. I thought of using like an ArrayList but i have to return an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List` instead, which provides an `add` method to insert at a specific index. Convert the `List` to an int array at the end.

```java
static int[] createTargetArray(int[] nums, int[] index) {
    List<Integer> target = new ArrayList<>(nums.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) target.add(index[i], nums[i]);
    return target.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
}
```